# SharePoint Online Workflow Notes Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

I have a custom list the requires the user to enter some notes. I have a choice field that triggers a Workflow that will create a new item in a Task List. How can I transfer the information in the notes to the Task List Description Field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all , You should ba aware of The task cannot be edited after it's status become  `Completed`. So that to update `Description` column in Task List you should check if its `approval status` is `Pending`.
2. To update `Description` column for the assigned Task with `Note` Field at the current item do the following :

   - Create Assign task action.
   - Check if the associated task is pending
   - Update List Item for association Task List.

[image]

Comment: Where in this example are you telling SharePoint what Task List to assign the new Task? We have multiple Task Lists in our collection, Maybe I have missed a step in SharePoint Designer when I tried your example...

Comment: The task list that has been associated to your current workflow !

Comment: Open your workflow via Sharepoint Designer and check it's associated task list

Comment: ok I opened SharePoint Designer and went to my Workflow. When I click on Open Task List it opens the wrong one. How do I change which Task List is associated with my Workflow?

Comment: When you create a workflow you can't change its associated task list in SharePoint designer , but there's a workaround here https://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/walkthrough-how-to-move-or-copy-a-sharepoint-designer-2010-list-workflow-to-another-list-on-the-same-site-or-another-site/

Comment: My suggestion to you to test first the above steps with the current Task (I do it in my environment and worked ), if it's working we can move the workflow to new workflow or change the task list with the above workaround ,

Comment: OK so I found the setting and changed the related Task List. I set everything as you have in the picture but the Workflow Suspended with the following error:

Comment: RequestorId: b1c6a913-fed2-2823-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentException: AssignedTo at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at

Comment: System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation) Exception from activity Throw If Sequence

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.OperatingWebContextScope Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.SingleTask Then If Stage 1 Sequence Flowchart Sequence AddTask.WorkflowXaml_1dd9373d_016e_4a82_84c3_9de8129cbd99

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45580/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-itt4r-corp).

Comment: After a little work M.Qassas solved this perfectly! Thank you very much,